# Routing on all interfaces

Tags: openbsd, router

I recently got a small single board computer to replace the horrible router provided by my ISP.

Following this example:

https://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/example1.html

em0 is my WAN, em1 is an AP, and em2 is my wired network.

Everything works perfectly for my AP, I can connect to it with my laptop and ssh to the router without issue.

I configured em1 with:

```
echo 'inet 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.255' > /etc/hostname.em1
```

The trouble starts when I try to add em2 into the mix:

```
echo 'inet 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.255' > /etc/hostname.em2
```

(I would like to have my wired network on the same subnet as the AP)

Using an RPi for testing. When I plug my RPi into em1, it gets the ip address 192.168.0.4 and I can ssh into it.

When I connect it to em2, it doesn't get a dhcp lease at all.

From running ifconfig, I can see that while em1 includes the line:

```
inet 192.168.0.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.0.255
```

em2 doesn't have this line.

How do I get em2 to serve dhcp leases, the same as em1?

Comment: Which computer are which interfaces on?

Comment: All interfaces are on the router.

Comment: I cannot follow your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question directly, change `dhcpd_flags` on `/etc/rc.conf.local` to make it listen on both interfaces, e.g.

```
dhcpd_flags="em1 em2"
```

Having two interfaces on the same subnet is asking for trouble.  You might want to take a look at bridging the two interfaces, if you really want them both on the same subnet.  Something like:

`/etc/hostname.em1`:

```
inet 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.255
```

`/etc/hostname.em2`:

```
up
```

`/etc/hostname.bridge0`:

```
add em1
add em2
up
```

And then have `dhcpd` listen on bridge0.

Comment: Thank you! One question: routers provided by my ISP have all ports on the same subnet, why is it not an issue for those routers, but it's a problem for a homebrew router?

Comment: Do they have different IPs on each port?  You can check this by seeing if both wired and wireless clients get the same gateway IP address. I think that usually those devices have the wireless interface bridged with the ethernet interface, with the router exposing a single IP address for all the LAN.